# como ordenar numeros de mayor a menor con expresion lambda

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new   ArrayList<Integer>();
    numeros.add(3);
    numeros.add(90);


    List<Integer> elementoRepete;

    elementoRepete = numeros .stream()
            .filter(p -> p......)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    elementoRepete.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: no sabemos cuanto vale `numerosenteros` favor de poner un [mcve]

Comment: numerosenteros es un arrayList<Integer> que contiene numeros ya agregados  posteriormente y lo que  quiero es ordenarlos de mayor a menor en la lista llamada elementoRepete

Comment: no se puede ver eso en tu código amigo, tu ejemplo no es completo

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te envió un código que resuelve tu inquietud.

```
public void ordenarNumeros(){ // Metodo para dar orden al ejemplo. Puedes modificar la firma para reutilizar el mismo
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>(); // Se crea un arreglo
    numeros.add(1); // Se agregan los numeros
    numeros.add(29);
    numeros.add(-3);
    numeros.add(8);
    numeros.add(17);


    numeros.stream() // Se trata el arregle como flujo de datos
           .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // Se forza a ordenarse en orden reverso
           .forEach(System.out::println); // se muestran todos los elementos ordenados


}
```

Comment: Te sugiero realices un ejemplo de acuerdo a lo que pregunta el OP, revisar [answer].